# Google Analytics Custom Dimension to Google Ads Similar audience

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, ads, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I'm trying to figure out if this works. Unfortunately I do not have a website to test this with. Though I've read the GA and GAds documentation I'm not sure if this is possible. So please bear with me.

Imagine a simple website that has Google Analytics (with a linked GAds account) deployed. I want to run a survey on this site users can answer if they like to. As the result of the survey the participants are assigned some ID. Lets say the result variable is called **cluster** and the values are **A, B or C**.

What I want to do now, is use this group of participants of the survey and try to target new visitors that are similar to the ones that have been assigned a **C** value via Google Ads.

As far as I understood the documentations this is how it could be done. Please correct me and point me in the right direction if I'm wrong.

1. I'm setting up a custom `user` dimension called **Cluster** in GA
2. I'm editing the GA code on the website to include the custom dimension that will be populated with the result of the mentioned survey
3. When the results come into GA, I'm creating a remarketing audience in GA called **Cppl** based on the custom dimension **Cluster**
4. I'm importing this **Cppl** remarketing audience into GAds
5. I'm creating a similar audience in GAds based on **Cppl** list
6. I'm publishing a campaign based on this similar audience

Does this process make sense and is it correct or am I making any mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to me, once you have defined the segment you need in Google Analytics you can use it for remarketing in Google Ads.

Comment: building similar audiences on top of the remarketing list is also possible?

Comment: In Google Analytics you can create a segment on which to then apply remarketing in Google Ads but you cannot pass a remarketing list to Google Analytics on which to apply a segment.